# Doc.new shortcut does not work anymore? I get 400 error

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace

I'm trying to create a new doc or sheet (Sheet.new) and gets 400 error.
[image]

Is the shortcut still working?

Comment: Do you have the link of the affected file so it could be tested? I checked my shortcuts and the only one that fails is the one from a file that is not owned by me and was taken to the trash.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/accounts/SetOSID?authuser=0&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fu%2F0%2Fcreate%3Fusp%3Ddot_new%26pli%3D1%26authuser%3D0&osidt=ALWU2cvJho6ITMdIkjl3LALjqzkLT2-pVA993MUEfy4kmuIIURw31Vm3SKc_BuIGz1WqjWKdqLKX-Rmz3zJ1mNo0S4EXdQTwjX7H5oECjLsExCnzwFpkJcTdR0TLaoQkaDFCMCKKIPTk-m_zKMzHHtLwk99syxFMxE-eZANs3pR0SsvjGrzDWEIvYWsAZoTHz7nd5pNFVpMdRxn7XS2793KsW4HyP01xag&ifkv=AQN2RmWc1-iSBe8rphEWmNEbio6JH_qN6osTzrPFb9Gyti6baqRi1EoY4myUJLjsQVUbN15DPtlepQ

Comment: The shortcut to create new files  is still working. I would suggest testing it on an incognito window either with the same Google account or a new one, you might be having some cache and cookies issues. If that is the case I would be adding the context as an answer.

Comment: With the same Google account, it works in Incognito. 
It didn't help to clean up cache, but I notice that if i'm refreshing the page with the error, It did open a new Docs page as expected.
Do you have any other suggestions to avoid the error and the need to refresh the page?

Comment: We might be looking at the extensions that you might have in your browser. Generally the incognito window has no cache and cookies and no extensions thay could he blocking or redirecting when utilizing the shortcut are activated, is like a fresh start browser.